# Principle branch of $\sqrt{1-z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am asked to find the principle branch of the complex function $$f(z) = \sqrt{1-z}$$

I know that the principle branch of $z^{1/2}$ is given by $\exp(\frac{1}{2} \log(z))$ where $$\log(z) = \log(|z|)+i\arg(z)$$ is the principle branch of the logarithm. So then to find the principle branch of $\sqrt{1-z}$, is it just

$$\exp\bigg(\frac{1}{2} \log(1-z)\bigg)$$
with $\log(1-z)$ being the principle branch of the logarithm i.e. $$\log(1-z) = \log(|1-z|) + i\arg(1-z).$$

I think I am confusing myself. Is the principle branch correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify what you do with the arg(1-z) when $z$ winds around 1 (and the arg increases with $2\pi$). You will have to introduce a cut (where arg, whence $\sqrt{1-z}$ is not defined), a typical choice here being $[1,+\infty[$ along the positive real axis. This is compatible with the principal branch of Log(w) which is usually defined by a cut along $R_-$.

Comment: What about the radius of convergence of the Taylor series for this function around z = 0. Is the same ? |z|<1 ?

Comment: If the cut does not enter the unit disk then the Taylor series converges for $|z|<1$ as you say. There are less natural choices of the cut for which the radius of convergence may be smaller than one, even zero (if the cut goes through the origin).

Comment: So It if they ask me in an exam to explain detailed the set of all complex numbers in which this series converges, did you recommend me to define that branch cut $[1,\infty)$ and then say that it is $|z| < 1$ ?

Comment: More like: The Taylor series for $\sqrt{1-z}$ around $z=0$ is $1-\frac{z}{2} + ...$ and converges for $|z|<1$ regardless of other things. It converges to a function which is analytic for $|z|<1$ and which coincide with the function $\sqrt{1-z}$ when defined in the complex plane with a branch cut going from $1$ to $\infty$ without intersecting the unit disk (so in particular $[1,+\infty)$ along the real line will do).